# Using Powershell, uncommenting a line in a configuration file

Tags: xml, powershell, config, session-state

I have two Session State nodes commented out in a configuration file. How do I uncomment only the first Session State node using Powershell?

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <!--<sessionState allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" mode="SQLServer" sqlCommandTimeout="150" sqlConnectionString="SessionConnectionString"></sessionState>-->
  <!--sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="500"></sessionState-->
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3):

**Easy way**: Text-manipulation using regex. Find something unique in the line you want to uncomment. Ex:

```powershell
# Get-Content is in ( ) to read the whole file first so we don't get file in use-error when writing to it later
(Get-Content -Path web.config) -replace '<!--(<sessionState allowCustomSqlDatabase.+?)-->', '$1' | Set-Content -Path web.config
```

[Demo @ Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dV7uY2/1)

**Hard way**: Xml-manipulation. I've taken the first comment here, but you could easily search for a specific node like we did above if that's better:

```powershell
$fullpath = Resolve-Path .\config.xml | % { $_.Path }
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $fullpath)

# Find first comment
$commentnode = $xml.configuration.'system.web'.ChildNodes | Where-Object { $_.NodeType -eq 'Comment' } | Select-Object -First 1

# Create xmlreader for comment-xml
$commentReader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create((New-Object System.IO.StringReader $commentnode.Value))

# Create node from comment
$newnode = $xml.ReadNode($commentReader)

# Replace comment with xmlnode
$xml.configuration.'system.web'.ReplaceChild($newnode, $commentnode) | Out-Null

# Close xmlreader
$commentReader.Close()

# Save xml
$xml.Save($fullpath)
```

Comment: Using the XML-manipulation method, a 'Constructor not found error is thrown. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type System.IO.StringReader' - I have tried many methods to get this node uncommented however they all seem to fail at the first hurdle...recognising the commented line as a node

Comment: That's probably because your `$commentnode.value` is null (you didn't find a commentnode matching your where-statement). Why not use the text-replacement? Usually you know (have a unique identifier) for the node you want to modify.  I tested both methods with your sample input before answering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for this

```
(gc settings.xml -Raw) -replace "<!--(.+?)-->",'$1'
```

This might be problematic in some edge cases in which case you could get XML comments via this code:

```
([xml](gc settings.xml)).configuration.'system.web'.'#comment'
```

Then you can `AppendChild()` to adequate place constructing xml node from comment string.